# Why does it keep saying ImportError: No module named pydot when I have already installed the module through pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pydot

I used command `pip install pydot`to install module pydot but whenever I try to run a certain file through terminal it says the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/parser.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pydot
ImportError: No module named pydot
```

I have done endless checking to make sure it was properly installed. I did check it in the python folder and it is there, indeed.

Does anyone know what am I missing? Is there something wrong with how it was installed?

I am using a macOS.

Thank you very much!

Comment: try to run like this : python3 script.py or python2 script.py and let me know

Comment: Try `pip3 install pydot`.

Comment: @seralouk thank you!! lol it worked *facepalm* huhu

Comment: @Josh thank you! I already tried that one too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check where the module is installed (type the following in the console):

```
pip show numpy
```

This returns the following for me (Macbook):

```
Name: numpy
Version: 1.14.0
Summary: NumPy: array processing for numbers, strings, records, and objects.
Home-page: http://www.numpy.org
Author: NumPy Developers
Author-email: numpy-discussion@python.org
License: BSD
Location: /Users/lab/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: tensorly, tensorflow, tensorflow-tensorboard, scipy, patsy, pandas, nitime, nipype, mxnet, matplotlib, Keras, h5py
```

You can see the location field:

```
Location: /Users/lab/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

This means that to make it run properly, I need to use:

```
python2 myscript.py
```

If you want to use **python 3.** then use

```
pip3 install pydot
```

and then

```
python3 myscript.py
```

Comment: thank you very much for this! this fixed my problem :)

Comment: I am glad that I helped.